# finding the Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

I have a question about the Jordan normal form:

Assuming we have a $3$-dimensional vector Space $V$ over the field of complex numbers. 
We have a linear map $f: V \to V$ and we know that the rank of the image of $f$ is $2$.
Furthermore we know that $f$ has no non-zero eigenvalues.

Apparently it follows that the Jordan normal form must be
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

My question is why does the Joran normal form look like this?

Answer (score 1):

Because all eigenvalues of $f$ are zero, the Jordan form (up to rearranging the blocks) must be one of the following:
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \quad
\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \quad
\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}.
$$
Now, which of these has a rank of $2$?

Comment: but why does it have to have rank of 2? Sorry I had Linear Algebra a couple of years ago and clearly I am missing something.

Comment: @Shirya Do you know the definition of the “rank” of a matrix or linear transformation?